# In featuretools, How to control the application of where_primitives?

Tags: featuretools

In `featuretools` we have various primitive application control mechanisms to custom apply the primitives to select `entities` and columns.

They are very neatly documented [here](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/guides/specifying_primitive_options.html)

> The `ignore_entities` and `ignore_variables` parameters of DFS control entities and variables (columns) that should be ignored for all primitives. This is useful for ignoring columns or entities that don’t relate to the problem or otherwise shouldn’t be included in the DFS run.

> Options for individual primitives or groups of primitives are set by the primitive_options parameter of DFS. This parameter maps any desired options to specific primitives.

Using `primitive_options` I can control the application of primitives to the individual entity or, more granularly, to columns within each entity. I can also control the columns by which I groupby to apply `groupby_trans_primitive`.

I cannot find (i have searched enough to think it does not exist) how to control the application of where primitives.

For example: say, I have a column for `spend`. I create a `seed_feature` to create buckets on the `spend` column. I might want to create the feature `min(spend)` on the whole. But, within the bucket [10000,15000], I might not want to create the `min(spend where spend_bucket == 10000_15000)`. How do I go about having this kind of control where I control primitives application only when `where` clause is in effect

Answer (score 0):

Currently the ability to control where primitives via `primitive_options` does not exist.

Potentially using `drop_contains` with a substring could give the desired control.

This issue will track adding support for this to Featuretools:
https://github.com/alteryx/featuretools/issues/1514

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion regarding how to go about it. Actually, the github issue linked is raised by me only